# How to use build parameter in email template of TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

How can use build parameters that were set due the build process in an email template located in `ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\config\_notifications\email` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the TeamCity forum. You can use build parameters by:

```
${build.parametersProvider.all['test']}
```

Comment: It seems like I provided more detailed answer earlier.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution. It gives you all the build parameters in a nice and neat format.

```
 <#list build.parametersProvider.all?keys as param>
    ${param} - ${build.parametersProvider.all[param]}
    <br>
 </#list>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use teamcity build parameters in this way:

Environment Variables (env.):
`${build.parametersProvider.all['env.NOTES']}`
Configuration Parameters:
`${build.parametersProvider.all['TAG']}`

Parameters `TAG` and `env.NOTES` are configured on `Build Configuration Settings` page.